# Evitar resultados duplicados de un array en PHP

Tags: php, array, string

Tengo un script para imprimir 5 palabras al azar de un array.
Ahora pasa que el script imprime 5 palabras pero alguna se repite una o varias veces.
Quisiera saber como hacer para evitar resultados duplicados, que sigan siendo 5 palabras pero que no se repitan las palabras.
Alguien sabe como hacerlo?
Paso el script.

```
<?php 
  $palabras = array("casa","perro","arbol", "rio", "lluvia", "nube", "sol","pasto"); 
  $contar = count($palabras);
  for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
    $rnd=rand(0, $contar -1);
    echo $palabras[$rnd];
 } 
?>
```

Saludos y muchas gracias!
Pablo

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo combinando [**`shuffle()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-slice.php), que hace una mezcla aleatoria de los elementos del array, y [**`array_slice()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-slice.php) para obtener los `N` elementos que te interesan del array anteriormente mezclado.

Haciendo eso no necesitas recorrer el array con un bucle:

```
$palabras = array("casa","perro","arbol", "rio", "lluvia", "nube", "sol","pasto"); 
shuffle($palabras);
$mRand = array_slice($palabras, 0, 5);
print_r($mRand);
```

**Salida:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => pasto
    [1] => rio
    [2] => perro
    [3] => arbol
    [4] => nube
)
```

... O cualquier otra, aleatoria, pero sin repeticiones.

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por tu respuesta.